# How to upgrade chromedriver in Windows 7?

Tags: npm, selenium-chromedriver

before I have chromedriver 2.32.498550.

- I delete all cache (`C:\Users\JHONE\AppData\Roaming\npm`)
- I install new version (2.37):

Command line:

```
npm install -g chromedriver
```

Traces:

```
C:\Users\JHONE>chromedriver -version
ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a)

C:\Users\JHONE>npm install -g chromedriver
C:\Users\JHONE\AppData\Roaming\npm\chromedriver -> C:\Users\JHONE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\chromedriver\bin\chromedriver

> chromedriver@2.37.0 install C:\Users\JHONE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\chromedriver
> node install.js

Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/chromedriver_win32.zip
Saving to C:\Users\JHONE\AppData\Local\Temp\chromedriver\chromedriver_win32.zip
Received 781K...
Received 1568K...
Received 2352K...
Received 3136K...
Received 3270K total.
Extracting zip contents
Copying to target path C:\Users\JHONE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\chromedriver\lib\chromedriver
Done. ChromeDriver binary available at C:\Users\JHONE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\chromedriver\lib\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe
+ chromedriver@2.37.0
added 96 packages in 20.139s
```

But my default version do not change (2.32.498550 again):

```
C:\Users\JHONE>chromedriver -version
ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I display all process and I see a old chromewebdriver.exe runned by RobotFramwork. I stop this process and I remove this chromewebdriver.exe and now it works.

```
C:\Users\JHONE>chromedriver -version
ChromeDriver 2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7)
```

but if I restore this chromewebdriver.exe, do not work again:

```
C:\Users\JHONE>chromedriver -version
ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a)
```